# docker container support with RDLC report in asp.net core

Tags: c#, docker, rdlc

I have Asp.Net core 3.1 web api, which is used to generate rdlc reports in PDF,curretnly it is working fine on local, but when i containerized it, it is not able to generate report, i got exception "An error occurred during local report processing".
The error occurs when i try to Render report in PDF.
Below is the Docker Script:-

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 5004
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5004
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5001

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
        libc6-dev \
        libgdiplus \
        libx11-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DotNetCoreApi/DotNetCoreApi.csproj", "DotNetCoreApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DotNetCoreApi/DotNetCoreApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DotNetCoreApi"
RUN dotnet build "DotNetCoreApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DotNetCoreApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final

WORKDIR /app
COPY BrandonGrotesque-Bold*.ttf c:/windows/fonts/
COPY BrandonGrotesque-Light*.ttf c:/windows/fonts/
COPY BrandonGrotesque-Medium*.ttf c:/windows/fonts/
COPY BrandonGrotesque-Regular*.ttf c:/windows/fonts/
COPY FreightNeo W03 Bold*.ttf c:/windows/fonts/
COPY FreightNeo W03 Medium*.ttf c:/windows/fonts/
COPY HelveticaNeueCyr-Light*.ttf c:/windows/fonts/
COPY Myriad Pro Condensed*.ttf c:/windows/fonts/
COPY MyriadPro-LightCond*.ttf c:/windows/fonts/
COPY TimesLTStd-Roman*.ttf c:/windows/fonts/
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DotNetCoreApi.dll"]
```

Community support is appericiated.

Comment: Are the packages you use, supporting unix systems? (check warnings in your IDE)

Comment: I am using windows, and i can not see any warning, Do i need to add report in docker container.?